# How can I pass a combination of architectures to a MLPClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network

I need to create a `MLPClassifier` with `hidden_layer_sizes`, that is a tuple specifying the number of neurons in the hidden layers.

For example: `(10,)` means that there is only 1 hidden layer with 10 neurons. `(10, 50,)` means that there are 2 hidden layers, the first with 10 neurons, the second with 50 neurons and so on. I want to test each of them in sequence.

I have passed this dictionary:

```
hl_parameters = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,), (50,), (10,10,), (50,50,)]}
```

And defined `MLPClassifier` like this:

```
mlp_cv = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=hl_parameters['hidden_layer_sizes'], max_iter=300,       alpha=1e-4, solver='sgd', tol=1e-4, learning_rate_init=.1, verbose=True, random_state=ID)
mlp_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But when I fit the model, I got this error:

```
TypeError                                    

    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [65], in <cell line: 9>()
      8 mlp_cv = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=hl_parameters['hidden_layer_sizes'], max_iter=300, alpha=1e-4, solver='sgd', tol=1e-4, learning_rate_init=.1, verbose=True, random_state=ID)
----> 9 mlp_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py:752, in BaseMultilayerPerceptron.fit(self, X, y)
    735 def fit(self, X, y):
    736     """Fit the model to data matrix X and target(s) y.
    737 
    738     Parameters
   (...)
    750         Returns a trained MLP model.
    751     """
--> 752     return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py:385, in BaseMultilayerPerceptron._fit(self, X, y, incremental)
    383 # Validate input parameters.
    384 self._validate_hyperparameters()
--> 385 if np.any(np.array(hidden_layer_sizes) <= 0):
    386     raise ValueError(
    387         "hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got %s." % hidden_layer_sizes
    388     )
    389 first_pass = not hasattr(self, "coefs_") or (
    390     not self.warm_start and not incremental
    391 )

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

I cannot find a solution. How do I solve this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing multiple architectures / hyperparameters to find the best model is a task for [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

Here's an example testing the four architectures in the question:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10_000)

# Initialize MLPClassifier with some parameters
clf = MLPClassifier(max_iter=300, alpha=1e-4, solver="sgd", tol=1e-4, learning_rate_init=.1)

# Search over `hidden_layer_sizes`
search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid={'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,), (50,), (10,10,), (50,50,)]}, n_jobs=-1, verbose=3)
search.fit(X, y)

print(search.best_params_)
```

Which shows us that the best cross-validation performance `hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10,)`

```
{'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10)}
```

Answer (score 1):

MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=**hl_parameters['hidden_layer_sizes']**, max_iter=300, alpha=1e-4, solver='sgd', tol=1e-4, learning_rate_init=.1, verbose=True, random_state=ID)

that field is an issue...you are providing a list of tuples as input for hidden_layer_sizes. MLPClassifier can only take tuple for hidden_layer_sizes.

if you need 3 hidden layers with 10, 50 and 50 neurons, just put (10,50,50) for hidden layer sizes. If you are testing different configurations, you can make a list of tuples and loop through the different combinations one at a time instead of putting the full list.

Comment: Thanks, so I can’t pass the four different architectures at the same time right?. In this case, first of alI, I want to test a NN with an hidden layer composed of 10 neurons. Then a NN with a hidden layer of 50 neurons. 
Moreover a NN composed of two hidden layers of 10 neurons each and finally a NN of two hidden layers with 50 neurons each.

Comment: You can build 4 different NN and compare result of each NN. MLP can only accept one tuple as input.